# No taskbar in remote desktop, how to solve and/or how to open cmd without taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, remote-access

### Problem:

When I connect to my  work computer via remote desktop, I cannot get the taskbar:

- pressing the  `Win logo` button does nothing;
- hovering  the mouse over the bottom of the screen does nothing; also
- Win logo + X does nothing. With this, I cannot run any program. Any way to run programs in this situation? Any ideas of how to debug this? I even cannot run the Event viewer. On the other hand, I can connect via ssh and run the  terminal separately from remote desktop, but then I cannot run any GUI  program, though I can run text-only commands, such as `tasklist`,etc. outside of remote desktop session
  How can I debug the problem?

### Setup:

- local: Windows 10 Home with 3 monitors,
- remote: Windows 10  Ultimate,
- I don't have physical access to the remote computer ( though I have SSHaccess: Bitvise SSH server is acyive).
- RDP clent: Windows buit-in.
- session: [X] Use all available monitors checked. open in  Full screen (maximized window).

---

i can

Exactly this setup used to work OK for years.

---

---

---

### What works OK:

- Alt-Tab works OK. But Win-Tab does nothing in the remote session.
- I can interact with controls in already open windows, and
- I can drag already open windows by the title bar,  within one monitor or between monitors.

---

### I thought possible causes might be some of:

-Maybe the remote computer is short of memory (72% in use, but 2.2 GB free)

- Some  days ago I  ran on the remote computer a program that triggered the ACL prompt, which is a modal window, blocking all other windows: maybe it is still active ?
- Some days ago I ran on rthe remote computer a program that might consume 100% or so CPU
- Some days ago  there was a network failure when a remote session was open, so maybe it did not close correctly?

---

### What is NOT the cause:

- in the remote desktop profile, the option Local Resources|"Apply Windows  key combinations" is set to "When using the full screen" and the session is open in full screen.
- or, maybe there is a window open with " on top of other windows property set", but no idea how to detect this.

Comment: Maybe explorer in not starting. Are you able to send Ctrl+Alt+Delete? Can you see the desktop?

Comment: I take it `Win`+`r` doesn't open the Run dialog either? Can you see the taskbar if you use windowed mode instead of full screen?

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I solved the problem in this trivial  way:

- I knew  that in the remote session, here was was a program   open in  GUI which needed to be properly closed via its GUI before reboot to prevent its data from corruption;
  In the remote session,  Using Alt-Tab, I found that  program, so  its window appeared, and I successfully  closed it.
  -I opened a terminal on the remote computer via SSH ( I use the Bitvise SSH client).
- in the terminal, I said  shutdown -r and prayed for  the server to come back, before it does not always reboot on itself after it shuts down (simetimes  it rquires to be turned on manually, physically, so it was very risky to reboot it remotely), and prayed for it not to decide to spend ours on installing the useless updates.
- After a few minutes, I was able to connect to the server again via RDP, which now works as expected, normally showing the taskbar.

---

Please see the comments to this question above, which hint at better ways to solve the problem (but I saw them too late). -- Thanks to those who kindly commented on my question!